# Changing from address but not sender account with outlook PropertyAccessor

Tags: email, outlook

I am trying to send from a specific outlook account using SendUsingAccount, but then I want to change the From address so it shows a different address to that of the sending account.

So I am doing the following:

```
Mail.SendUsingAccount := Outlook.session.accounts.item(SenderAccount);
mail.propertyAccessor.SetProperty('http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1F001E', senderAddress);
Mail.send
```

Mail is an olMailItem.

The setProperty function is not raising an exception, however, the from address for the email is being shown as he email address of the sender account.

Comment: Did you try to use the [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-sentonbehalfofname-property-outlook) property instead?

Comment: Did you try to call the `Save` method after?

Comment: Are you trying to send using a completely arbitrary address? A proxy alias of the primary user? Or an address of some other Exchange mailbox?

Comment: An address of some other Exchange mailbox.